# How does one create a multiple "syncronous" repository remote GIT branch in intelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-branch

I have a large intellij project that has 12 git roots and have it set for "synchronous" repository/git root management.

I can easily create a new local branch on all the repos, but I can't figure out how to push out the new branch to a *new*remote*branch* on all the corresponding remote repositories.

Push even when I specify "use alternative remote" always comes back with "nothing to push" and does nothing.

I can push each repository from the command line but that is mighty in convenient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select all repositories in the push dialog, as well as the "Push to alternative branch" checkbox, it should work fine.
However, I suspect that you experience [an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104846) that was introduced in 12.1 and was fixed recently for 12.1.2 (not released yet).

Comment: That is the issue - I have that version and it doesn't work :)